# The proof of the Lagrange's Rational Function Theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request

Lagrange's rational function theorem states that if one has two rational functions in multiple variables $f(x_1,x_2,...x_n)$ and $g(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$ then one can can express $f$ as a rational function in $g$ if and only if the set of permutations that keep $g$ unchanged is a subset of the set of permutations that preserve $f$.

A slightly more precise statement of the theorem can be found here in the first paragraph of this paper [here](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1926-32-06/S0002-9904-1926-04274-9/S0002-9904-1926-04274-9.pdf).

Is anyone familiar with the proof of this theorem? While it is fairly clear that if $f$ can be expressed in terms of $g$ the set of permutations that keep $g$ unchanged has to be the subset of those that keep $f$ unchanged, the converse is far from obvious.

Comment: Note that your statement as given isn’t true, as the linked article points out, you also need elementary symmetric functions. As an easy example, you can’t express the sum of $x_i$ as a rational function in the product of the $x_i$.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the field $K = \mathbb{Q}(x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_n)$, and consider $K_g \subset K$ to be the subfield generated by $g$. Define
$$
H_g = Aut(K/K_g) = \{\sigma \in Aut(K) : \sigma(\alpha) = \alpha \quad\forall \alpha\in K_g\}
$$

Similarly, define $K_f$ and $H_f$. Then you want to show that
$$
K_f\subset K_g \Leftrightarrow H_g \subset H_f
$$

If all the hypotheses are satisfied, which I think they are, this is merely the Fundamental Theorem of Galois Theory

Comment: Thanks, I am however more interested if there is a way of proving that, that doesn't directly invoke the Galois correspondence. (Something closer to what Lagrange might have had in mind.)

Answer (score 1):

In Harold M. Edwards' [Galois Theory](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387909806) pp. 33-34, he includes a translation of Section 104 of Lagrange's *Réflexions* (1771) in which Lagrange first presents the theorem and includes a proof. The theorem, as originally stated by Lagrange, is translated as:

> "If $t$ and $y$ are any two [polynomials] in the roots $x', x'', x''', \dots$ of $x^\mu + mx^{\mu-1} + nx^{\mu-2}+[px^{\mu-3}+]\cdots = 0$ and if these [polynomials] are such that every permutation of the roots $x', x'', x''', \dots$ which changes $y$ also changes $t$, one can, generally speaking, express $y$ rationally in terms of $t$ and $m, n, p, \dots$, so that when one knows a value of $t$ one will also know immediately the corresponding value of $y$"

Edwards goes on to prove this by using Cramer's rule (c. 1750) though he notes Lagrange takes a more general approach (related to his use of *generally speaking*).

Let $t$ and $y$ be the polynomials in the $n$ roots and $t_1, t_2, \dots, t_k$ denote the distinct polynomials from $t$ under the permutation of the roots. Since we assume a permutation that fixes $t$ fixes $y$, there are at most $k$ distinct polynomials $y$ can take under permutation of the roots. Call them $y_1, y_2, \dots, y_k$ such that the permutations that carry $t$ to $t_i$ carry $y$ to $y_i$. Now consider the $k$ polynomials

$$
y_1 + y_2 + \cdots + y_k, \\
t_1y_1 + t_2y_2 + \cdots + t_ky_k, \\
t^2_1y_1 + t^2_2y_2 + \cdots + t^2_ky_k, \\
\vdots \\
t^{k-1}_1y_1 + t^{k-1}_2y_2 + \cdots + t^{k-1}_ky_k.
$$

Observe that these polynomials are symmetric in the roots $x', x'', x''', \dots$ since any permutation of the roots results in a rearrangement of the summands. Now because they are symmetric in the roots, they are expressible in the elementary symmetric polynomials (i.e. the coefficients $m, n, p, \dots$ of our original equation) by the Fundamental Theorem of Symmetric Polynomials. Call them $s_1, s_2, \dots, s_k$.

What is left to show is that $y_1 = y$ can be rationally expressed in terms of $t_1 = t$ and the coefficients $m, n, p, \dots$. Here he uses Cramer's rule with our $k$ equations $\sum_i t_i^j y_i = s_j$ where $s_j$ is expressible in $m, n, p, \dots$. Then $y_i = D_i / \Delta$ where $\Delta$ is the [Vandermonde determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix) and $D_i$ is the determinant from replacing the $i$th column of $\Delta$ by the column of $s_1, \dots, s_k$. We want to how that $y_i = D_i/\Delta = D_i\Delta / \Delta^2$ is rationally expressible in $t_1$.

Edwards makes the stipulation that $\Delta^2 = \prod_{k<i}(t_i - t_k)^2$, the discriminant of $F(X) = \prod (X-t_i)$, is nonzero, i.e. that $F(X)$ has no multiple roots. He indicates that Lagrange handles this case in a more general argument but Edwards does not present his proof.

Observe that any permutation of the $t_i$ other than $t_1$ changes the sign of the both $D_1$ and $\Delta$ but leaves their product $D_1\Delta$ unchanged. So $D_1\Delta$ can be viewed as a polynomial in $t_1$ that is symmetric in $t_2, \dots, t_k$, and is expressible in the elementary symmetric polynomials
$$\begin{align}
\tau_1 &= t_2 + t_3 + \cdots + t_k \\
\tau_2 &= t_2t_3 + t_2t_4 + \cdots + t_{k-1}t_k \\
&\vdots\\
\tau_{k-1} &= t_2t_3\cdots t_k\end{align}.
$$

But then we can express these in terms of the elementary symmetric polynomials in all $t_1, \dots, t_k$ called $\sigma_1, \dots, \sigma_k$

$$
\begin{align}
\tau_1 &= \sigma_1 - t_1 \\
\tau_2 &= \sigma_2 - t_1\sigma_1 + t^2_1 \\
&\vdots\end{align}.
$$

Thus $D_1\Delta$ and further $y = y_1 = D_1\Delta/\Delta^2$ is rationally expressible in $t_1$ and $\sigma_i$'s, which are in turn expressible in $m, n, p, \dots$.

Comment: It seems to me that the $t_i$ must be distinct in the setting of the OP's question: If two of the $t_i$ were equal, then $t$ would have a larger symmetry group. (I say "in the setting of the OP's question" because I suspect that Lagrange may have been talking about rational functions in the roots of some particular polynomial with $\mathbb{Q}$ coefficients, not about formal rational functions.)

Comment: @DavidESpeyer I believe the $t_i$ are assumed to be distinct in Edwards argument--both in the sense they are symbolically different, i.e. the expression in terms of $x', x'', x''', \dots$ which I believe is what Lagrange was thinking of since each $t_i$ is defined as a distinct expression upon permutation of the roots, and numerically on evaluation (which is the stipulation Edwards imposes with the discriminant)